# Ubuntu 17.10: high CPU usage by gnome-shell 3.26.1

Tags: gnome, 17.10, cpu, gnome-shell

The `gnome-shell` process often uses up close to 100% of the CPU time.

Obligatory graphics info:

```
$ lspci | grep -i vga
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 5500 (rev 09)
$ glxinfo | grep -i render
direct rendering: Yes
OpenGL renderer string: GeForce 930M/PCIe/SSE2
(more lines)
```

I'm also using the following extensions:

- Applications menu
- Dash to panel
- No topleft hot corner
- Touchpad indicator